# Unable to decrypt my encrypted string in a substitution cipher

Tags: php, encryption

I am developing my own encryption and decryption algorithms. My encryption function is working fine, but my decryption function is not working properly. The following are my functions:

```
<?php
function encrypt($os,$mode=64,$pattern="tyv9xXa2iUEMhZLD6YlF4BOjg8AdJz0nVHKPRTpb5smfQ1WwroIkqcN3eSG7Cu"){
    $ns="";
    for($i=0;$i<strlen($os);$i++){
        $ns.=$pattern[(strpos($pattern,$os[$i])+$mode)%strlen($pattern)];
    }
    return $ns;
}
function decrypt($os,$mode=64,$pattern="tyv9xXa2iUEMhZLD6YlF4BOjg8AdJz0nVHKPRTpb5smfQ1WwroIkqcN3eSG7Cu"){
    $ns="";
    for($i=0;$i<strlen($os);$i++){
        $ns.=$pattern[abs(strpos($pattern,$os[$i])-$mode)%strlen($pattern)];
    }
    return $ns;
}
echo decrypt(encrypt("abcde"));
?>
```

My expected output is: `abcde`

But the output returned is: `ejUPa`

Comment: `abs` is certainly not a good choice here.

Comment: Could you describe in words, how exactly the two functions are supposed to work?

Comment: Simple, Encrypt function goes through each letter and returns +64 indexed character (by default), which is working fine. Decrypt function has to do the opposite of the encrypt function.

Comment: This isn't really a encryption function. I really hope you aren't using this for security.

Comment: @ScottArciszewski Nope, this is just out of curiosity and first step to learning how encryption works.

Comment: All right. :) This might help: https://github.com/paragonie/awesome-appsec If you find anything useful in your travels, please feel free to suggest it.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Fixed it:

```
$ns.=$pattern[abs(strpos($pattern,$os[$i]))-$mode%strlen($pattern)];
```

In your decrypt ^^.
Just a matter of bracket placing.

Full fixed code:

```
function encrypt($os,$mode=64,$pattern="tyv9xXa2iUEMhZLD6YlF4BOjg8AdJz0nVHKPRTpb5smfQ1WwroIkqcN3eSG7Cu"){
    $ns="";
    for($i=0;$i<strlen($os);$i++){
        $ns.=$pattern[(strpos($pattern,$os[$i])+$mode)%strlen($pattern)];
    }
    return $ns;
}
function decrypt($os,$mode=64,$pattern="tyv9xXa2iUEMhZLD6YlF4BOjg8AdJz0nVHKPRTpb5smfQ1WwroIkqcN3eSG7Cu"){
    $ns="";
    for($i=0;$i<strlen($os);$i++){
        $ns.=$pattern[abs(strpos($pattern,$os[$i]))-$mode%strlen($pattern)];
    }
    return $ns;
}

echo decrypt(encrypt("abcde"));
```

Hopefully you can understand the difference yourself.

---

And now to fix the issue with spaces:

```
$pattern=" tyv9xXa2iUEMhZLD6YlF4BOjg8AdJz0nVHKPRTpb5smfQ1WwroIkqcN3eSG7Cu"
```

Take note of the space at the beginning of the string.

---

An additional note due to comments...

Should you wish to change $mode to let's say 62, you would need to shorten $pattern appropriately.
e.g.

```
function encrypt($os,$mode=62,$pattern=" tyv9xXa2iUEMhZLD6YlF4BOjg8AdJz0nVHKPRTpb5smfQ1WwroIkqcN3eSG7"){
    $ns="";
    for($i=0;$i<strlen($os);$i++){
        $ns.=$pattern[(strpos($pattern,$os[$i])+$mode)%strlen($pattern)];
    }
    return $ns;
}

function decrypt($os,$mode=62,$pattern=" tyv9xXa2iUEMhZLD6YlF4BOjg8AdJz0nVHKPRTpb5smfQ1WwroIkqcN3eSG7"){
    $ns="";
    for($i=0;$i<strlen($os);$i++){
        $ns.=$pattern[abs(strpos($pattern,$os[$i]))-$mode%strlen($pattern)];
    }
    return $ns;
}

echo decrypt(encrypt("abcde"));
```

Works just fine, notice $pattern is now missing the last 2 characters.

Comment: Works only for `abcde` but when I try `Hello World` or any other, its not working :(

Comment: The perfect answer! Thanks a ton

Comment: Anytime, I managed to learn a few things myself, so thanks too.

Comment: I am sorry... the answer is not completely right. If you use $mode = 62 for example it fails.

Comment: I don't think you understand what $mode does. Read the comments in the question.

Comment: just test your solution with a different mode. And yes i DO understand what $mode does. It basically shifts the index by the given $mode value (default: 64).

Comment: clearly you don't... Because you would realise you would need to shorten $pattern. I will update my answer for you.

Comment: but you understand, that $pattern must include every char that has a $possible input. if you reduce $pattern to size 62 then you only have 62 possible input chars instead of 64

Comment: Indeed so, but in what case would you change mode? On top of that, I doubt we should be taking this so seriously. He was just trying things out. after all.

The issue lies in his encryption method that utilizes mode%strlen($pattern), but that was never the question that needed to be answered.

Comment: Well, if you introduce a $mode variable in the function signature, developers should be able to change it ;). The main problem here is the wrong use ob abs(). But you are right, maybe we should'nt take this too seriously. If OP is fine with your solution ( which works perfectly on the default $mode = 64 case ) it is all fine ;)

Comment: This code doesn't work, because `%` has a higher precedence than `-` and `abs` should not be used at all. Try `decrypt(encrypt("abCde"));` (note the uppercase `C`) with the default values.

Comment: Not exactly, the uppercase C is merely due to uppercase C not being included in $pattern.

Comment: @Valdorous It is included. It's the second before last character.

Comment: Also can the comments stop now? The answer has been accepted and we all agree this isn't best practice. But I think it's enough now.

Comment: I'm referring to my final answer where I remove the last two to show the $mode = 62 working due to an above comment. And now explaining why remove the last two cause C to no longer work.

Which also shows you did not read / check my answer properly. As I clearly stated having removed the last two characters in the $pattern

Answer (score 2):

The encryption works in this way:

```
$new_char_index = ($char_index + $shift) % $alphabet_length;
```

where the modulo `%` handles the wrap around so that the new index is still in the alphabet range. This works well for positive numbers, but doesn't work like you would expect it to for negative numbers. Here are some examples:

```
echo -3 % 7; // -3
echo -11 % 7; // -4
```

That is why simply changing `+` for `-` doesn't work:

```
$new_char_index = ($char_index - $shift) % $alphabet_length;
```

This *can* lead to negative numbers. You can't access arrays with negative numbers in PHP, but you could do that in Python.

The easy fix is to make sure that the resulting index is always a positive numbers. You've tried that with `abs()`, but the problem is that this doesn't correctly wrap around from the other side of the alphabet, but only removes the sign which is wrong.

An easy fix is adding the alphabet length before the modulo operation in order to get a positive number:

```
$new_char_index = ($char_index - $shift + $alphabet_length) % $alphabet_length;
```

This works, because `$alphabet_length % $alphabet_length == 0`. It wraps to the correct position of the alphabet.

Now you only have to make sure that `$shift` is already in the alphabet range:

```
$shift = $shift % $alphabet_length;
```

One final improvement: you can use the same function for encryption and decryption, because the `$enc_shift == -$dec_shift` and the last formula should give you work for both.

Answer (score 1):

This is not encryption. This is a variation on a [Caeser cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher).  Simply put, you should **never** implement your own encryption (unless you know *exactly* what you're doing...).  This would do for obfuscation and nothing more.

As for the code itself, I suspect its an order of operations issue. Simply replacing a `+` with a `-` won't reverse the operator precedence in the `encrypt()` function.  A handy generic string rotation function you could adapt is in the comments of [this php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-rot13.php) page.

If you want encryption there are many good articles about solid encryption; [this](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/using-encryption-and-authentication-correctly) is my personal opinion of a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that works with every $mode and $pattern size. 
You have to notice that you can only "encrypt" chars that are contained in $pattern.

```
<?php
function encrypt($os,$mode=64,$pattern=" tyv9xXa2iUEMhZLD6YlF4BOjg8AdJz0nVHKPRTpb5smfQ1WwroIkqcN3eSG7Cu"){
$patternLength = strlen($pattern);
if($mode < 0) {
    $mode = ($patternLength - $mode) % $patternLength;
}
if($mode >= $patternLength) {
    $mode %= $patternLength;
}
$ns="";
for($i=0;$i<strlen($os);$i++){
    $ns.=$pattern[(strpos($pattern,$os[$i])+$mode)%strlen($pattern)];
}
return $ns;
}

function decrypt($os,$mode=64,$pattern=" tyv9xXa2iUEMhZLD6YlF4BOjg8AdJz0nVHKPRTpb5smfQ1WwroIkqcN3eSG7Cu"){
$patternLength = strlen($pattern);

if($mode < 0) {
    $mode = ($patternLength - $mode) % $patternLength;
}

if($mode >= $patternLength) {
    $mode %= $patternLength;
}

$ns="";

for($i=0;$i<strlen($os);$i++){
    $pos = strpos($pattern,$os[$i]);
    if($pos >= $mode ) {
        $ns .=  $pattern[$pos - $mode];
    } else {
        // $pos - $mode is negative so we need + sign
        $ns .= $pattern[$patternLength + ($pos - $mode)];
    }
}
return $ns;
}
```

To test this, you could do something like that:

```
$failed = false;
for($mode = -128; $mode <= 128; $mode++) {
    // include all possible chars in the test to see if encryption and
    // decryption works for all.
    $allChars  = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 ";
    if(decrypt(encrypt($allChars, $mode), $mode) != $allChars) {
        echo "mode ".$mode." failed<br>";
        $failed = true;
    };
}

if(!$failed) {
    echo "success";
}
```